# How to use flock in PHP?

Tags: php

In my php code, I want to create a reader/writer code. So there will be a file that the php code wither reads or writes to. There can only be 1 writer, or there can be many readers, but you can write and read at the same time.

How can this be done in PHP? I believe you need to use the `flock` code?

Comment: What do you want to know that isn't covered by the first example at http://au1.php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm with [Danack's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15305296/how-to-use-flock-in-php#comment21603309_15305296) - the [php documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php) of `flock()` contains a very good example:

```
$fp = fopen("/tmp/lock.txt", "r+");

if (flock($fp, LOCK_EX)) { // exclusive lock will blocking wait until obtained

    fwrite($fp, "Write something here\n");

    // or ...

    execute_code_that_shouldnt_run_twice_at_the_same_time();

    flock($fp, LOCK_UN); // unlock
} else {
    echo "failed to obtain lock";
}

fclose($fp);
```

Note that `flock()` in default mode will blocking wait until it can obtain the lock. This is regulary the case if the other process obtains the lock currently.

---

But don't expect too much from the `flock()` function. It is using so called *advisory locks*, which can be ignored by other processes. On Linux for example PHP's `flock()` is using the kernel function `flock()`, `man 2 flock` explains how it works:

> flock() places advisory locks only; given suitable permissions on a
>   file, a process is free to ignore the use of flock() and perform I/O on
>   the file.

Meaning `flock()` will just give an advice to other processes. If they don't care about they can read or even write regardless of the lock ( or type of lock). However the man pages are about Linux other system may handle this differently. (It's not the case actually)

But, however as you are the coder of the processes you can / and should care about the lock using `flock()` every time you access the file. But you cannot be sure that another process - like a text editor - will not overwrite your file

Comment: Will this code allow for multiple people to read from the file at the same time? Also how can you detect if a file is being read from before you start writing?

Comment: @omega Yes, other processes are allowed to read and write(!) to the file. They can just not obtain the lock. Didn't know before

Comment: Should flock open lock files with `r+` or `w+` or just `w`? I see some examples with just `w`. What's the effect in this case?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai Good question! No, it does not matter for the functionality of `flock()` itself. However, `w+` would make sure, that file gets created if it not exists. Also take into account, that if you want to use `flock()` to synchronize operations on a file, you might simply use that file as the lockfile, and then the mode used by `fopen()` depends on what you are actually want to do with that file.

Comment: Great, so I guess `w+` should be the recommended way of setting it up. Especially where the lock file might be deleted for whatever reason.

Comment: It depends, but `w+` looks indeed like a convenient way for various use cases.

Comment: If the PHP process died in the midst of holding the lock, is there some way of releasing locks from dead processes?

Comment: If one uses `w+` doesn't this mean 2 processes might truncate the file, would this affect locking synchronisation across 2 processes? (I'm assuming the file itself contains information on which process is holding locks)

Comment: In this scenario `a+` looks more appropriate.

Comment: What about the process dieing scenario?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82696/discussion-between-hek2mgl-and-cmcdragonkai).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to read and write at the same time, well you can't. It's unsafe behaviour. Just use exclusive lock to write, and your readers (using shared lock) will block while waiting to be able to read it. That way they're never able to read from a part-finished file, but will always be able to read eventually.

Oh and don't lock the file for longer than you need to. If you're making prolonged changes (e.g. waiting on network activity), lock it, update, unlock, wait until you get more data, lock it, update, unlock. Or better yet, buffer the data internally and write it in one go.