# PHP fopen (x flag) guaranteed to run only once?

Tags: php, web-applications, locking, mutex, fopen

PHP allows us to use the `x` flag when doing [fopen](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php):

> Create and open for writing only; place the file pointer at the
>   beginning of the file.
>
> **If the file already exists, the fopen() call
>   will fail by returning FALSE** and generating an error of level
>   E_WARNING.
>
> If the file does not exist, attempt to create it. This is
>   equivalent to specifying O_EXCL|O_CREAT flags for the underlying
>   open(2) system call.

Does this mean that no matter how many concurrent fopen requests we have (from different users), **it is guaranteed that the file will only be created once and never overwritten?**

```
if ($handle = fopen("part006", "x+b")) {
    do_some_processing();
    echo "You managed to process.";
    /*

    can we guarantee that only 1 user (http request)
    will ever process the function and see the
    message "you managed to process" ?

    */
} else {
    echo "You failed to process.";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer: It is guaranteed that the file will be only created once and never being overwritten , as long as other processes also use O_EXCL. If they do not, the file can be overwritten. So, opening (creating) a file using  O_EXCL means not, that the file is somewhat *write protected*

Explanation: fopen uses the underlying `open` syscall. From the man page: `man 2 open`

> O_EXCL
>
> If O_CREAT and O_EXCL are set, open() shall fail if the file exists. The check for the existence of the file and the creation of the file if it does not exist shall be atomic with respect to other threads executing open() naming the same filename in the same directory with O_EXCL and O_CREAT set. If O_EXCL and O_CREAT are set, and path names a symbolic link, open() shall fail and set errno to [EEXIST], regardless of the contents of the symbolic link. If O_EXCL is set and O_CREAT is not set, the result is undefined.

Comment: Is exclusiveness guaranteed for windows too?

Comment: I'm not sure (but it is likely) .. Will try to find that information.. (unfortunately `man` does not work on windows ;) )

Comment: @Pacerier Read some mailing list and it seems that this will not work on windows. but I'm not sure as I currently have no windows for testing. can you test? If it does not work, then you should use `flock()` for that purpose. It's not the same, but it might help you (don't know you application needs).. Note my answer to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15305296/how-to-use-flock-in-php/15305346#15305346) which is `flock()` related and may help

Comment: I've got no php on windows for testing too. was simply thinking about portability.

Comment: Will test it later and drop a comment. `flock()` will work on windows.